# How to avoid 'any' and provide correct type in typescript code?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

My task is to improve the current TypeScript, avoiding using `any` type at the same time. The thing is that sometimes it is pretty hard to understand what should be there instead as part of the code is a legacy code.

Could you please give me any tips how to look for the proper types in the cases that are not that obvious (besides obviously hovering over some things)?

What would be the best way to investigate this `payload` thing and `X,Y,Z`?

I know `any` is okay when used with some 3rd party libraries etc. but what about these cases for example? How should I avoid `any` in cases like HOC when testing the type of the thing is much harder?

```
export default ({ classes, label, payload }: Props): JSX.Element => (
  <div className={classes.background}>
    <Typography className={classes.label} variant="subtitle2">
      {label} - {payload.find((item) => item.dataKey === 'value')?.value || '-'}
    </Typography>
  </div>
);

interface Props {
  classes: Partial<ClassNameMap>;
  label: string;
  payload: any;
}
```

---

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

export default (WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType) => ({ X, Y, Z }): JSX.Element => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!X.length) {
      Y();
    }
  }, [X, Y, Z]);

  return (
    <WrappedComponent />
  );

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This technical debt kind of work is always a bit of a slog. But it will help you hone your skills with TypeScript.

Looking at your first snippet above, what I would do is look at how that function uses that prop. You can see that it uses a `find` method, so this is a good indicator that it is an `array` type. Furthermore, the array seems to contain values called `item` that have a `dataKey`, which gives you a starting point to find what exactly an `item` is. Assuming somewhere in your codebase there is an `Item` interface or type, you can import that type and define the `payload` as `Item[]`.

The second example is a lot more difficult. Maybe this is X, Y and Z coordinates. Or maybe it is just badly named. The only way to identify this would be to search the codebase for the usages of that component and go from there.

Comment: I think in second one X can be either string or array since it uses length property and Y can be some function. I am not sure but these are just assumptions.

Comment: so as I thought - there is no golden rule here and every single time I need to investigate it and look for the clues... big thanks to ya guys, will continue my detective work then, haha :)